# Máscara aceitando letras e números

Tags: jquery

Utilizo uma máscara *Jquery* dessa forma, porém preenche somente números:

```
$("#FormaCalculosVencimentos").mask("000,000,000");
```

Surgiu a necessidade de digitar letras e números apenas no primeiro item, de cada vírgula, ficaria assim `T15` ou `015`, sendo possível digitar tanto letra como números, mas somente no primeiro.

Exemplo:

```
T15,020,T20
```

Não sei se ficou claro, vi que em algumas documentações aceitava o `*` ou `?` para letra e números, porém não funcionou. Qual caractere que fica como letra e número?

O usuário não tem um limite, ele pode escrever o tanto que ele preferir, porém sempre o primeiro, pode ser letra ou número, e o resto só números.

Assim:

```
T05,025,032,T58 etc
```

Comment: me de um exemplo completo de números que vão entrar. pelo mask que voce ta usando é obrigatório o usuario escrever 999,999,999, os 9 numeros. seria isso mesmo ?

Comment: apresente um [MCVE]

Comment: Editei a resposta, explicando um pouco melhor, ele pode digitar quantos caracteres ele quiser.

Comment: @marianac_costa o usuário poderia digitar tanto `B12, B33, J11` como `B12, B33, J11, H11, J22, K78, ...` seria isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode indicar a que a posição pode receber uma letra utilizando o `A`

```js
$("#FormaCalculosVencimentos").mask("A00,A00,A00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="FormaCalculosVencimentos" type="text" />
```